# Are 煤碳 and 煤炭 the same thing ("coal")?

Tags: difference, word

> 此前，船舶经纪公司Braemar ACM Shipbroking珀斯分部的分析师阿比那·古普塔（Abhinav Gupta）向ABC确认，42万吨澳大利亚**煤碳**在今年7月、8月卸货，另外5.5万吨在今年5月装船的煤碳在7月清仓，但他无法确认这些**煤炭**的用途。
> <sub>[中国今年前三季度对澳洲进口额突飞猛进意味着什么？](https://www.abc.net.au/chinese/2021-10-16/china-australia-import-value-growth-trade-war-beijing-canberra/100541920)</sub>

Sometimes I encounter [煤炭](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E7%85%A4%E7%82%AD) = "coal" whereas sometimes I encounter 煤碳 (such as in the above), and I'm not sure if there's a subtle difference here.  I don't see 煤碳 in Pleco, so perhaps it's just a typo.

**Question**: Are 煤碳 and 煤炭 the same thing ("coal")?

Comment: It should be 煤炭.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to《现代汉语规范词典》:

> 非金属元素，符号C。有两种同素异形体，即晶质碳和非晶质碳。晶质碳有石墨和金刚石，非晶质碳有木炭、煤、焦炭等。化学性质稳定，在空气中不起变化，是构成有机物的主要成分。在工业和医药上用途很广。

You can say that 煤炭 or 煤 is composed of 碳. So It's a typo.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is a typo. Usually 碳 means chemical element C.